# Is there any order of dictionary value print in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

When we print values in a dictionary, is there any default sorting that use to print the keys and values in a Python dictionary? Or do they randomly print the key , value pairs?

Please see below code.
is there any order of dictionary value print in python?

```
confusion = {}

confusion[1] = 1
confusion[4] = 22
confusion['5'] = 2
confusion['2'] = 2
confusion[1.0] = 4
confusion['1'] = 2

print confusion
```

The result is `{'2': 2, 1: 4, '1': 2, '5': 2, 4: 22}`

Comment: or maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928/645956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to have the insertion order maintained. By default, python's `dict` does not maintain the order.

Answer (score 1):

No, dictionaries are by definition unordered. What you see here might change from version to version and platform to platform